# WindowsXP with no drivers

Tags: windows-xp, formatting

So I formatted my windows XP and reinstalled it. But forsome reason my drivers disk is for the wrong Dell Model.....

So I can't connect to the internet because I think I'm missing the ethernet driver. Am i screwed or can I obtain theses drivers elsewhere....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[support.dell.com](http://support.dell.com) has the drivers available for download. Just type in your service tag or model and select your OS and everything is right there.

Comment: Okay you were faster. :) | Put the driver to a pendrive and install it from there.

Comment: I find using this method to be "better" since the support site often has more updated versions of the drivers. Usually, what I do is I install from a Windows disc, then I use another computer to grab the network driver from the website, copy it over using a flash drive, install it, and then download the rest of the drivers directly on the reinstalled computer.

Comment: Going to the manufacturer's website is either step #1 or #2 in a reformat, for sure.